# how to check whether file exists before using path in Jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a jrxml which has a node as follows,

```
<image>
  <reportElement x="181" y="0" width="209" height="74"/>
  <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["logo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

How can I check whether physical file logo.jpg exists or not?
If doesn't exists, how to fall back to a default image "default.jpg"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<variable name="LOGO" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression>
        <![CDATA[(new File("logo.jpg").isFile())? "logo.jpg":"default.jpg"]]>
    </variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression>
        <![CDATA[(new File("logo.jpg").isFile())? "logo.jpg":"default.jpg"]]>
    </initialValueExpression>
</variable>

<image>
  <reportElement x="181" y="0" width="209" height="74"/>
  <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$V{LOGO}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

[Got clue from this site](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/542178/checking-existence-image-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) in the Java code, if that's what you're using to check with. Not quite sure if you're asking for another approach that involves the XML itself.

If file doesn't exist, then you would just map the default image.

Answer (score 0):

Send your image path using parameter or field in jasper report. for example I am sending image path using field.Name of field is image `imagePath`. If you have a image named `logo.png` , path of image as string other wise set path of default image.
and write this syntax with image.

```
<image>
    <reportElement uuid="0db5b93f-46e4-4aaa-aac9-5a6d090d7eb6" x="127" y="23" width="206" height="78"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Enjoy...